Question regarding minimum time taken to move a point onto a line joining two points
This question is regarding the following problem
A bird is at a point $P(4, –1, –5)$ and sees two points $P_1(–1, –1, 0)$ and $P_2(3, –1, –3)$. At time $t = 0$, it starts
flying with a constant speed of $10 m/s$ to be in line with points P1 and P2 in minimum possible time t. Find
t, if all coordinates are in kilometers.
First i decided to find the vector which describes the line joining $P_1$ and $P_2$, this is the displacement vector between the two points which happens to be $4\hat{i} - 3\hat{k}$.
Next i wanted to find the point on the line which is at a minimum distance from the bird, obviously this is the point on the line which lies on the perpendicular from the point on which the bird is onto the line.
I decided to find the the point however could only get a magnitude using the following formula
$$|\vec{b}| = \frac{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}}{|\vec{b}|}$$
However after this i could not go anywhere may be it is possible to find the coordinated of the point using direction cosines?
Could anyone point me in the right direction any help would be appreciated!
